# How to view core ruby documentation locally?

Tags: ruby, rdoc

I have installed Ruby 2.0.0 with rvm and want to have local html documentation. So I run

```
$ rvm docs generate
Installing rdoc-data................................................................
Generating gems documentation.......
$ rvm docs open
rdoc docs are missing, perhaps run 'rvm docs generate' first?
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what works for me for RVM:

```
rdoc $MY_RUBY_HOME -o ~/ruby_docs
```

That puts the HTML documentation for the core and standard libraries in your $HOME/ruby_docs directory. Then, if you're on Mac OS, simply run:

```
open ~/ruby_docs/index.html
```

or navigate to the directory and open index.html somehow for other OSes.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using this app https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/dash-docs-snippets/id458034879?mt=12 Allows you to access documentation for any language.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'll give this app a try. But its nice just to have rdoc html on my laptop.

Comment: @Lexsys this will still give you access to the docs locally. its just another means to an end.

Answer (score 0):

Try `gem update rdoc` and then generate the docs. I had the same issue and this solved it.

Comment: Do you have a '.rvm/docs/ruby-2.0.0/rdoc folder in your home directory? What operating system do you use?

Comment: There is no such folder:
`$ ls ~/.rvm/docs/
alt.md   color.md  upgrade-notes.md
`

Comment: I am on mac os x 10.9

Comment: `gem update rdoc` would update the rdoc gem, but won't do anything for the core library documentation.